# Broke my Flask-sqlalchemy sqlite db instance

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate, sqlalchemy-migrate

While testing my Flask applications functionality i somehow broke my db by editing my models during up/downgrading. I am using Migrate for this purpose but i am fairly new to it. which leads to my question: How do I completely reset my db(Migrate revisions). Before when something like this happened i would just downgrade to init state and manually delete all python files from Migrate/versions folder.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

1. just delete whole migrations folder
2. do flask db init
3. check if migrations folder was created(check all necessary files from screenshot)
   [Screenshot of necessary files in migrations folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wvpR.png)

4. flask db migrate
5. flask db upgrade
Now you have an db matching the models from your application